# Convert a List into an Option if it is populated

Tags: list, scala, scala-option

I have a method that should convert a list to an `Option` of an object, or `None` if the list is empty.

```
def listToOption(myList: List[Foo]): Option[Bar] = {
  if(myList.nonEmpty) Some(Bar(myList))
  else None
}

case class Bar(fooList: List[Foo]) {}
```

For some reason, my solution feels rather inelegant, and not the Scala way. It seems I should be able to use a method on `List` to do this sort of thing, but I can't wrap my head around it.

Is there a more Scala-like way to do this?

Comment: I first thought that you wanted the head of the list when present but then I re-read your question I really do not understand why you would want to do this. It's hard finding a idiomatic way to do stuff when it's not a common operation. It would be nice if you could clarify what you are going to use this functionality for.

Comment: From a wider perspective, it was already clear to me that there are some design problems in this class I'm working with, but I chose not to refactor the class and instead try to write something elegant given the weird restraints. My `if-else` solution merely felt lacking, and I thought there could be a better way to do it.

Comment: I've been doing Scala for about 9 months, and I truly find it to be awesome, but it's both a blessing and a curse that you can do stuff exactly how you want to do it. I would have refactored the crap out of that code.  Well thanks for the clarification, and GLHF coding Scala!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Lee's answer is good, but I think this corresponds to the intention a bit more clearly:

```
Option(myList).filter(_.nonEmpty).map(Bar)
```

Answer (score 20):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, `Option` has a [`when`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/Option$.html#when[A](cond:Boolean)(a:=%3EA):Option[A]) builder:

```
Option.when(condition)(result)
```

which in our case gives:

```
Option.when(myList.nonEmpty)(Bar(myList))
// val myList = List[Int]()    =>    Option[Bar] = None
// val myList = List(1, 2)     =>    Option[Bar] = Some(Bar(List(1, 2)))
```

Also note [`Option.unless`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/Option$.html#unless[A](cond:Boolean)(a:=%3EA):Option[A]) which promotes the opposite condition:

```
Option.unless(myList.isEmpty)(Bar(myList))
// val myList = List[Int]()    =>    Option[Bar] = None
// val myList = List(1, 2)     =>    Option[Bar] = Some(Bar(List(1, 2)))
```

Answer (score 15):

```
myList.headOption.map(_ => Bar(myList))
```

Comment: The force is strong with this one.

Comment: @CoryKlein - I'm not sure this is actually better than an explicit match since it seems a bit messy to ignore the value.

Comment: But the sheer brevity of it!

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
Some(myList) collect { case(l@hd::tl) => Bar(l) }
```

Seems pretty scala-esque to me.

Comment: You could also use `case l if l.nonEmpty`.

Answer (score 2):

```
import scalaz._; import Scalaz._
myList.toNel.map(Bar)
```

`toNel` - is "to non-empty list" here, it returns `Option[NonEmptyList]` for safety:

```
scala> case class Bar(a: NonEmptyList[Int])
defined class Bar

scala> List(1,2,3).toNel.map(Bar)
res64: Option[Bar] = Some(Bar(NonEmptyList(1, 2, 3)))

scala> List[Int]().toNel.map(Bar)
res65: Option[Bar] = None
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us give some imperative style to get the requested output, pls give a look below snippet. Hope will be helpful

```
def sequenceBase[A](a: List[Option[A]]): Option[List[A]] = {
  //match the list[option[A]]
  a match {
    case e: List[A] => {
      
      //this is similar to lift which helps to convert the Option to actual value.
      def map1(element: Option[A]): A = element match {
        case Some(a) => a
        case None => throw new IllegalArgumentException("None...!")
      }
      
      //this will help to return the list of values from the map1 return 
      Some(for (i <- a) yield map1(i))
    }
    
    //if one of the values is none we are not going to process further
    case List(None, _) => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid")
  }
}

//actual runner
println(sequenceBase[Int](List(Some(1), Some(3), Some(3))))
```