# scala idiomatic way of transforming a list to an option

Tags: scala

What might be the most idiomatic way for turning any scala collection into an `Option` of the same collection, whereas when the collection is empty, the option would be `None` and otherwise just a `Some` of the original?

Oh, and without making scala create a memory copy of the entire collection for that humble conversion.

`Option.apply` is suited for translating `null` to `Option` of type `None`, a nice legacy-wrangling utility, but useless for idiomatic scala seeking the following semantics:

```
val some = Option(List(3,4,5))
val none = Option(List()) // seeking None, rather than Some(List()) here
```

Comment: I'd question the need for that. In my experience, an empty collection represents an "empty result" or "no results" just fine - no need to wrap it in an additional option.

Comment: @Zoltán I do not totally disagree. When however would you really reap benefit from options in your school of thought?

Comment: when you may or may not return a *single* value. The `find` method on collections is a very good example.

Comment: I agree with Zoltán. I can't see how wrapping a `List` in an `Option` in this manner is going to buy you anything. `Options` should be used when there is a possibility of no result at all. An empty `List` is not the same as no `List` (and as a matter of practice, if empty `Lists` are represented as `Nones`, then how to represent no `List`?) All the usual monadic operations for `Lists` (i.e. `map`, `flatMap`, `filter`, etc.) are defined on empty `Lists`, and for things like `head` which expect a non-empty `List`, we can use pattern matching, `headOption`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Yes - of course nothing and an empty list are not the same kind of information. However in type hierarchies where both singular types and lists of types are siblings, an `Option` wrapper may sometimes make sense, for some of the methods that consume the common inherited type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a List into an Option if it is populated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244262/convert-a-list-into-an-option-if-it-is-populated)

Comment: I disagree with @Zoltan. In many cases, I am attempting to communicate AT THE TYPE LEVEL to my API user the distinction of a non-empty collection which works great by encoding it within the `Option` type. Here is my favorite answer that I have found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54328140/501113

Answer (score 5):

I'd probably just go with a filter call after creating the Option:

```
scala> Option(List()).filter(_.isNonEmpty)
res1: Option[List[Nothing]] = None

scala> Option(List(1,2,3)).filter(_.isNonEmpty)
res2: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2, 3))
```

Comment: I'd suggest `_.isNonEmpty`

Comment: Yes, that's better! Cheers, @Zoltán

Comment: One thing to note is that in the case where the collection is empty, an Option holding the empty collection is allocated and then thrown away after the filter is called.

Answer (score 4):

I feel like it is not a common thing to do and can't think of any common idiomatic way, what I can suggest is adding `toOption` method like this:

```
implicit class OptList[A](val list: List[A]) extends AnyVal {
  def toOption: Option[List[A]] = if (list.isEmpty) None else Some(list)
}
```

and use it as follows:

```
scala> List().toOption
res0: Option[List[Nothing]] = None

scala> List(615, 5).toOption
res1: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(615, 5))
```

`toOption` is a method in scala that appears in some other contexts, for example `Try` has `toOption` method.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Lukasz's answer, but more complete and works for any collection (I think all collections extend from `Traversable` as this image suggests https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dsptl.png) as requested.

```
object EnrichedCollections {

  implicit class CollectionOps[A <: Traversable[_]](val collection: A) extends AnyVal {

    /**
     * Returns None if the collection is empty, otherwise returns Some of the collection
     */
    def toOption: Option[A] = if (collection.isEmpty) None else Some(collection)
  }

}

import EnrichedCollections._

assert(Nil.toOption == None)
assert(Seq(1,2).toOption == Some(Seq(1,2)))
assert(Map.empty.toOption == None)
assert(Map(1 -> "hi", 2 -> "bye").toOption == Some(Map(1 -> "hi", 2 -> "bye")))
```

Comment: you could even declare it for anthing that has isEmpty method, but anyway I see no use for converting lists to option

Comment: You could, but if you do it with structural typing (`A <: { def isEmpty: Boolean }`), you would be doing a reflective call to check for `isEmpty`, which has different performance characteristics than this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun:

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
val option = list.headOption.map{_ => list}
```

However, I would question why you would want to do this... using `isEmpty` is a nice way of checking uniformly for empty lists or None values - you might find this avoids you having to convert to Option in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. Right on, but sometimes in elaborate object relationships, an option value bears a more generalized uniform meaning than a more specific size property of a collection. Mainly when some objects sharing a common ancestry are collections and some are not.